# Why does NSApplescript executeAndReturnError: seem to leak memory?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, osx-snow-leopard

I'm not sure, but this:

```
 -(void)quitFinder {
    NSAppleScript *restartFinder = [[NSAppleScript alloc] initWithSource:@"tell application \"Finder\" to quit"];
    [restartFinder executeAndReturnError:nil];
    [restartFinder release];
}
```

when called like this:

```
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(quitFinder) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
```

yields this:

[image]

in Instruments memory leak tool. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider switching to OSAKit. The API is very similar to NSAppleScript, but broader, so this should be close to painless.

If OSAKit doesn't leak, then the problem may very well be in NSAppleScript, and I'd recommend [filing a bug](https://bugreport.apple.com/) with your Instruments trace document attached.

Comment: Is OSAKit documented anywhere? (How do I get started using it?)

Comment: Never mind. After looking at the headers it seems as if all I need to do is replace NSApplescript with OSAScript.

Comment: It's not documented, but it is a public API. And yes, they're similar enough that you should be able to simply apply what you know about NSAppleScript.

Comment: @Vervious hey, I know 8 years passed, but did OSAKit help in memory leaks?

Answer (score 2):

Is this a one-time thing, or does it happen every time you call it? In the first case, it’s likely to be a false positive for some permanent state set up by OSA/AppleScript.

Comment: It seems to happen every time I call it, though. (But I also have another method called -(void)startFinder that's almost exactly the same and called in the exact same way that doesn't leak). Could something else be askew?